# Why do I have a sudden current peak when PWMing a valve?

Tags: pwm, solenoid-valve, current-sensing

I am driving a proportional solenoid valve with PWM from an MCU as follows:

[image]

The voltage of the MCU is 3.3 V. The gain of the amplifier is set to 20 V/V. Because the valve consumes 170 mA when fully opened, the maximum ADC voltage is 1.7 V with a 0.5 ohm resistor.

[TSC103 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tsc103.pdf).

[Datasheet of the valve](https://www.emerson.com/documents/automation/catalog-series-226-miniature-valves-proportional-asco-en-6775570.pdf)

Here are the curves at low frequency (100 Hz):

[image]

- Red is the voltage between ADC input and GND.
- Yellow is the voltage between the gate of the MOSFET and GND (Vgs)

It seems normal, but if I zoom in on the curves at the switching moment, here is what we can see:

[image]

(The frequency is now 40 kHz but this behavior is present whatever the frequency.)

As you can see there is a decreasing current for some μs when the transistor switches. At a higher duty cycle (90%), this is what I get:

[image]

(You can ignore the blue curve, it is the voltage between the anode of the diode and GND)

I do not understand what's causing this issue. The problem is that I need to measure the current passing through the valve when the PWM is 40 kHz, and at this frequency, the peak really becomes a problem.

Do you know the cause of this? What solution could I implement to solve it?

Comment: I can see red is current but, where is it measured. What is yellow and what is blue? What does this mean: *if I zoom on the curves when the gate is on when it is off* - it seems self-contradictory.

Comment: You do need a better gate driver circuit. Here, you're trying to charge a capacitor from an I/O pin. MOSFET capacitances between their terminals get ignored. You can see the gate voltage ringing at switch-off. Add a series resistor between the I/O pin and the gate. You can work out its value from the I/O's datasheet max output current (allowing for other I/O pin currents) then verify its suitability against the gate-drain capacitance. Also, please explain the other traces.

Comment: Voltage of MCU seems 3.3V ? Valve solenoid specs ? TSC103 : Table 7 for "time response" .... 20us, hum ?

Comment: If not sure it's a good idea to place the flyback across the current sense resistor. Also, is the current what the MCU is measuring? How do you filter and supply the ADC?

Comment: I have edited my post to add the missing informations.

Comment: Maybe measure the current sense amplifier inputs with AC-coupled probes.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the slew rate of the current sense amplifier, which should be in its datasheet (hint hint). If you probe the bottom of R1 do you see the sense amp output in miniature?

Comment: Slew rate of current sense amplifier https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tsc103.pdf   is 0.6 V/us ... from 10mV to 100 mV ...

Comment: You could hardly find a 40kHz switching for an industrial proportional solenoid valve. Typically is around 2kHz to 5kHz.

Comment: Driving & controlling at kHz, you are building a Boost converter, a sort of. While the Vgs = 0, the current backing up to full/saturation, only means the circuit wiring error. Why the picture #1 turns off well (the red trace), but not (#2 &) #3?

Comment: @Antonio51 That slew rate ties in reasonably well with the shape of the V on the second trace ... the inductive kick may be fast but the opamp can't follow. Reducing the BW of the input signal to keep the opamp out of slew limiting is a reasonable answer.

Comment: I do not want the solenoid valve to switch, the PWM is fast enough so that it does not have time to respond. Thus I can control its current. Regarding the difference between #1 and #2+3, the spikes were too fast on #1 to be visible but they were present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first trace is OK. Next of them are not. Possibly the issue is the gate driving circuit - you didn't measured the Vds, I don't believe you can drive the MOSFET at 40kHz without appropriate gate driver.

Next thing is the CMRR of the sense amplifier. You don't have any low pass filter on the input of the opamp.

As you can see the red trace is flat with some spikes, sure something is wrong.

EDIT:

[How to filter the input of a high-side current sensing](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4304-how-to-filter-the-input-of-a-highside-current-sensing-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[image]

[image]

At 100Hz

Vgs VS IL

[image]

---

At 40kHz DT=50%

IL

[image]

Vgs VS. IL

[image]

You should get a flat response at 40kHz.

Try to connect two probes on Rshunt and then use scope math to subtract.

[image]

Note that GPIO current is very high, assumed that ON/OFF resistance is 50 Ohm, but can be even higher. So you should group several GPIOs parallel and add external gate resistor. Then you turn ON/OFF GPIOs synchronously (not with digitalWrite() or similar command).

Comment: The first trace is probably only OK because the scope sampling rate is slow enough to miss the problem.

Comment: On the first trace it was not visible because the peaks are too quick compared to the time division (4 us VS 4 ms).
If I put a 1uF capacitor between ADC and GND, the ADC input is smooth enough to suit my needs... Is it a common practice to put a low pass filter at the input of a current sense amplifier ?

Comment: @JackOfHearts, yes, it is quite common, probably more on motors than solenoids. I think the flyback diode should be in parallel to L1, not the L1+R1 series.

Comment: @JackOfHearts As you see the signal from the opamp follows the max slew rate of opamp 0,6V/us, it means something weird happens at switch time and the opamp goes mad. It's better to filter the inputs of opamp rather than output. Placing the flyback diode  parallel to L is not an option, also the shunt has to be in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you turn off current to a coil, you'll get a voltage spike from back-emf. Noice that you'll also get some small spikes in some cases when you apply voltage to a coil.

You may reduce the current pulses a bit by putting the diode across the solenoid coil only (not including the 500 mOhm resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Here what happens if measuring resistor misplaced ... More easy to filter for R4

[image]

@40 kHz PWM, Other condition L/R = 4 ms as suggested

[image]

@ 4 kHz PWM

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the OP's solenoid is much larger. L/R is approx. 4ms (R = Rdson + R_solenoid + R_shunt + R_source_24V) while yours Tau is bellow 10us.

Comment: More easy to filter for R4 ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the recovery time of your diode here.  When the transistor switches off, the diode almost immediately switches from 24V reverse bias to a forward bias.  A small amount of charge is thus needed to achieve the bandgap conditions for conduction.  From the high-side sense resistor, which is in the flyback loop, it looks as though the current stopped flowing for a moment.